# Regular expression for groovy domain class property

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I have a property of type string.It may accept all numeric and alphanumeric values.
And i need an expression which must contains "-[0-9]" at end of the string
Like A-a-A2-AXY-1 and the following format

```
XX-XXX-X**-11** any string and at last **-number**
```

Comment: "-" is not alphanumeric.

Comment: ok,At the end it should have "-"and number.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, the pattern you require is something like:

```
/[0-9A-Za-z]+(-[0-9A-Za-z]+)*-[0-9]/
```

I wrote a quick test:

```
valid = [ 'A-a-A2-AXY-1', 'A-a-A2-A2Y-11', '14-a-A2-A2Y-11' ]
invalid = [ '-a-A2-AXY-A', 'A-a-A2-AXY-', 'A-a-A2-AXY-B' ]

pattern = /[0-9A-Za-z]+(-[0-9A-Za-z]+)*-[0-9]+/

valid.each { println "$it ${it ==~ pattern}" }
invalid.each { println "$it ${it ==~ pattern}" }
```

which outputs:

```
A-a-A2-AXY-1 true
A-a-A2-A2Y-11 true
14-a-A2-A2Y-11 true
-a-A2-AXY-A false
A-a-A2-AXY- false
A-a-A2-AXY-B false
```

So seems to work

The pattern can probably be shortened by use of wildcards

Comment: @Odaiah Cool!  Any chance of accepting as an answer? You've only accepted answers to 26% of your questions :-/